# UICollectionViewCell not shown properly

Tags: swift, cell, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following code. For some strange reason, the cell is not registering properly and the cell is not rendered.

I expect there to be 5 purple cells but instead there is only red background.

```
class RateController: UICollectionViewController {
    var user: User?

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .red

        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = .purple

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I pasted it right into a fresh project, defined the User class, made the necessary adjustments in the storyboard, and ran it:

[image]

So if there's a problem, it's somewhere else — not in that code!

---

I've been thinking about where else the problem could be; the problem you are describing would happen if you disabled the Flow layout in the storyboard and replaced it with an empty Custom layout, like this:

[image]

If you did that, set the Layout back to Flow.